# Change a script from onEdit (checkbox) to image assignment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script which right now works with checkboxes (onEdit).

**Current Script Usage:**

1. When you click the first checkbox which is located in 9th column and 2nd row of Charts Sheet, it adds an item located to Charts!B4 into Watchlist sheet.
2. When you click the second checkbox which is located in 9th column and 3rd row of Charts Sheet, it removes that item if it already exists in Watchlist sheet.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Charts') return;
  if (e.range.columnStart != 9) return;
  if (e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.value == 'TRUE') add_item(e);
  if (e.range.rowStart == 3 && e.value == 'TRUE') remove_item(e);
}

function add_item(e) {
  var [ss, item, favs_sheet, favs_range, favs, header] = get_variables(e);
  if (favs.includes(item)) { ss.toast(item + ' is already in watchlist'); return}
  
  favs.push(item);
  favs = [header, ...favs.sort()].map(x => [x]);
  favs_sheet.getRange(1,2,favs.length,favs[0].length).setValues(favs);
  ss.toast(item + ' was added to watchlist');
}

function remove_item(e) {
  var [ss, item, favs_sheet, favs_range, favs, header] = get_variables(e);
  if (!favs.includes(item)) { ss.toast(item + ' was not found among watchlist'); return }
  
  favs = [header, ...favs.filter(x => x != item).sort()].map(x => [x]);
  favs_range.clearContent();
  favs_sheet.getRange(1,2,favs.length,favs[0].length).setValues(favs);
  ss.toast(item + ' was removed from watchlist');
}

function get_variables(e) {
  e.range.uncheck();
  var ss = e.source;
  var item = e.range.getSheet().getRange('B4').getValue();
  var favs_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Watchlist');
  var favs_range = favs_sheet.getRange('B:B');
  var favs = favs_range.getValues().flat().filter(String);
  var header = favs.shift();
  return [ss, item, favs_sheet, favs_range, favs, header]
}
```

**What I want to achieve:**

I would like to change the script in order to work with images instead of checkboxes. So for example when you click on Image1 the script will add the item to watchlist sheet. If you click on Image2 the script will remove the item from watchlist sheet if it's already exist.

Thanks

Comment: Then what is your question? `I would like to change the script in order to work with images instead of checkboxes. So for example when you click on Image1 the script will add the item to watchlist sheet. If you click on Image2 the script will remove the item from watchlist sheet if it's already exist.`

Comment: Yes I want to convert the script you see above, to work with buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: @TheWizEd no, there is no any `onClick` event that one could to assign to a checkbox or image in the same way. The `onEdit()` trigger works with checkboxes. Image calls a function. It works quite different and the code needs some not obvious tweaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function add_item() {
  var [ss, item, favs_sheet, favs_range, favs] = get_variables();

  // make the condition case insensitive:
  var item_lower = item.toLowerCase();
  var favs_lower = favs.map(x => x.toLowerCase());
  if (favs_lower.includes(item_lower)) { ss.toast(item + ' is already in Favorites'); return}
  
  favs.push(item);
  favs = favs.sort().map(x => [x]);
  favs_sheet.getRange(2,1,favs.length,favs[0].length).setValues(favs);
  ss.toast(item + ' was added');
}

function remove_item() {
  var [ss, item, favs_sheet, favs_range, favs] = get_variables();

  // make the condition case insensitive:
  var item_lower = item.toLowerCase();
  var favs_lower = favs.map(x => x.toLowerCase());
  if (!favs_lower.includes(item_lower)) { ss.toast(item + ' was not found in Favorites'); return }
  
  favs = favs.filter(x => x.toLowerCase() != item_lower).sort().map(x => [x]);
  favs_range.clear();
  favs_sheet.getRange(2,1,favs.length,favs[0].length).setValues(favs);
  ss.toast(item + ' was removed');
}

function get_variables() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var item = sheet.getRange('E1').getValue();
  var favs_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Favorites');
  var favs_range = favs_sheet.getRange('A2:A' + favs_sheet.getLastRow());
  var favs = favs_range.getValues().flat();
  return [ss, item, favs_sheet, favs_range, favs];
}
```

So you will have two functions `add_item()` and `remove_item()`. You can assign any of them to image or drawing.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lZ9KTkdcajtnww5Ap9BVSmaOJlRE1bYddF1a4DIs_Wk/edit?usp=sharing) is my sheet.

[image]

I assigned the functions to the text buttons (drawings) but it can be done about the same way with images.

I think the code can be universal for buttons and for `onEdit()` at the same time. It can be done. But I think it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Hey again, I found a bug on the script. It's not case sensitive, so for example if Item1 is added on the watchlist and you try to add item1 it can not detect it because "i" is not capitalized. Any workaround? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I just added the four new lines to make the conditions case insensitive. But I haven't tried it. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Just tried that, it removes everything from favorites sheet and doesn't add the new item.

Comment: Try my sheet by the link in the answer. I just tried it and the buttons work fine. They add and remove the items as intended and ignore case. Probably your file has something that breaks my code.

Comment: Okay I will try and see what's going on. In the meantime can you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/128165094?noredirect=1
Thanks

Comment: About the next question, not sure if I can answer. It looks beyond my expertise. I will see it more close tomorrow. It's about 4:00 of morning at my place. Have to go to bed, sorry. ) Good luck. And Tanaike is a real master, try to ask him.

Comment: So i figured out what the problem is. When you remove an item, it deletes and cell up. This is okay however it shouldn't affect first row which has the column headers. That's the only issue right now. Also clear should be clearContent in order not to break format.

Comment: I fixed by changing: `var favs_range = favs_sheet.getRange('A2:A' + favs_sheet.getLastRow());` to: `var favs_range = favs_sheet.getRange('A:A');`